# confused by the break command of sqlplus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

From [documentation of sqlplus for break](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12009.htm)

When specify multiple on clause, sqlplus would search from the first on clause to the last on clause for a break. When it finds a break it will perform the actions in reverse order, from the last to first.

I connect to the scott schema and have some test:

```
SQL> break on deptno skip 1 on job skip 2
SQL> break
break on deptno skip 1 nodup
      on job skip 2 nodup

SQL> select deptno, job from emp order by deptno, job;    

    DEPTNO JOB
---------- ---------

        10 CLERK


           MANAGER


           PRESIDENT



        20 ANALYST

    DEPTNO JOB
---------- ---------
        20 ANALYST


           CLERK



           MANAGER




    DEPTNO JOB
---------- ---------
        30 CLERK


           MANAGER


           SALESMAN






 14 rows selected.

 SQL>
```

After print the first row(10, CLERK), there is a change in job, it just skips 2 lines, why not 3 lines ? In the second page, there are tow places sqlplus skip 3 lines. At the end of the report is skips 5 lines. Just don't know how it decides how many lines to skip when specify multiple on clause.

Comment: Can you re-run this with `set pagesize 50` so the page breaks and repeated headers aren't complicating the output? And include another (not-null) column in the query - you have multiple values for some dept/job pairs so some are just blankrows rather than skipped lines. (The row count doesn't match the displayed strings, which is a clue).

Comment: @Alex Poole Even I the pagesize to 50 rather than the default 14, sqlplus skips 2 llines sometime and skips 3 lines sometime when the value of job changes

Comment: Seems I got it, I will have a check. Thanks.

Comment: It works the way you asked it to work. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> After print the first row(10, CLERK), there is a change in job, it just skips 2 lines, why not 3 lines ?

Why would it skip 3 lines when you have mentioned **on job skip 2**. SQL*Plus did exactly what you asked it to do, to skip 2 lines.

> In the second page, there are tow places sqlplus skip 3 lines.

That is because you also mentioned **break on deptno skip 1** So, for a new department, there is one more line skipped. So, 2 lines skipped for job and 1 line skipped for department, thus a total of 3 lines skipped.

Also, for department 20, there are **2 ANALYST** and **2 CLERK**, so it skips 2 lines for each job.

```
SQL> break on job skip 2
SQL> select deptno, job from emp order by deptno, job;

    DEPTNO JOB
---------- ---------
        10 CLERK


        10 MANAGER


        10 PRESIDENT


        20 ANALYST
        20


        20 CLERK
        20


        20 MANAGER


        30 CLERK


        30 MANAGER


        30 SALESMAN
        30
        30
        30



14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

> At the end of the report is skips 5 lines.

Because, in the end for department 30, there are 4 SALESMAN, and there will always be an extra line before the total number of rows message is displayed.

```
SQL> set pagesize 50
SQL> select deptno, job from emp order by deptno, job;

    DEPTNO JOB
---------- ---------
        10 CLERK
        10 MANAGER
        10 PRESIDENT
        20 ANALYST
        20 ANALYST
        20 CLERK
        20 CLERK
        20 MANAGER
        30 CLERK
        30 MANAGER
        30 SALESMAN
        30 SALESMAN
        30 SALESMAN
        30 SALESMAN

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

The best way to understand this is, add another column without any skip for example add empno and see the lines which are actually skipped.

```
SQL> break on deptno skip 1 on job skip 2
SQL> select empno, deptno, job from emp order by deptno, job;

     EMPNO     DEPTNO JOB
---------- ---------- ---------
      7934         10 CLERK


      7782            MANAGER


      7839            PRESIDENT



      7788         20 ANALYST
      7902


      7876            CLERK
      7369


      7566            MANAGER



      7900         30 CLERK


      7698            MANAGER


      7654            SALESMAN
      7521
      7499
      7844




14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't seeing quite what you think. You're only querying the department and job columns, which can have duplicates - as more than one employee can be in each job. The `nodup` part of the break setting means duplicates of those two columns will not be shown; which means you are seeing a mix of rows with have both columns blanked as duplicates, and rows that are skipped.

I have a different table but for the same effect:

```
break on department_id skip 1 on job_id skip 2

select department_id, job_id
from employees
where rownum < 10;

DEPARTMENT_ID JOB_ID
------------- ----------
           90 AD_PRES


              AD_VP




           60 IT_PROG







          100 FI_MGR




9 rows selected.
```

If I add another non-null column, and/or the rownum pseudocolumn, you can see what is really happening:

```
    ROWNUM DEPARTMENT_ID JOB_ID     EMPLOYEE_ID
---------- ------------- ---------- -----------
         1            90 AD_PRES            100


         2               AD_VP              101
         3                                  102



         4            60 IT_PROG            103
         5                                  104
         6                                  105
         7                                  106
         8                                  107



         9           100 FI_MGR             108




9 rows selected.
```

Now you can see it skips two lines if the job changes within the department, and three when the department changes. Which is what you asked it to do.

You probably don't want to, but you could also just get the distinct values:

```
select distinct department_id, job_id ...

DEPARTMENT_ID JOB_ID
```

---

```
       90 AD_VP


          AD_PRES



       60 IT_PROG



      100 FI_MGR
```

4 rows selected.

... and again you'll see two skipped lines between jobs within a department, and three between departments.

You might also be confusing the description of the behaviour in the documentation; you said "When it finds a break" but it can find multiple breaks for one row in the results; the docs you linked to actually say:

> SQL*Plus searches each row of output for the specified breaks, starting with the outermost break and proceeding—in the order you enter the clauses—to the innermost.

With your query it will either match department, job, or both.

> Next, SQL*Plus executes actions beginning with the action specified for the innermost break and proceeding in reverse order toward the outermost break ... SQL*Plus executes each action up to and including the action specified for the first break encountered in the initial search.

The innermost break in your case is on job, the outermost on department. If the department didn't change but the job did then it will only find a matching break on job, and only the innermost skip (of two rows) will be applied. If the department changed - whether or not the job changed too - it will find a match on that, but will still apply all of the `on` clause from department onwards, in reverse order; so it will apply the `skip 1` from job *and* the `skip 2` from department; hence skipping three lines in total.

---

<sub>Yes I am using rownum without an order by, it happens to work better with this query and my data; don't try this at home</sub>